# What causes SSD write timeout over 120 seconds?

Tags: linux, mysql, xfs

system:CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)

kernel:Linux l-db11.tj.cn5 3.10.0-957.10.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Mar 18 15:06:45 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

SSD:Dera

cpu: 24 core

memory: 128G

The operating system can only write at a very small rate。

```bash
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
nvme0n1           0.00     0.00    2.00  130.00     0.03     0.91    14.67     0.00    0.03    0.00    0.03   0.03   0.40
nvme0n1           0.00     0.00    0.00  122.00     0.00     0.84    14.05     0.00    0.03    0.00    0.03   0.03   0.40
nvme0n1           0.00     0.00   16.00  201.00     0.25     3.83    38.53     0.01    0.03    0.06    0.03   0.03   0.60
nvme0n1           0.00     0.00    8.00  204.00     0.12     1.12    12.03     0.01    0.03    0.12    0.03   0.03   0.70
nvme0n1           0.00     0.00    0.00  154.00     0.00     1.05    13.95     0.00    0.01    0.00    0.01   0.01   0.20
nvme0n1           0.00     0.00    1.00  162.00     0.02     1.07    13.65     0.01    0.04    0.00    0.04   0.04   0.70
```

memory:

```bash
free -g
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            125          58          50           3          16          62
Swap:            63           0          63
```

dmesg:

```bash
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:24 2024] INFO: task mysqld:25801 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:24 2024] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:24 2024] mysqld          D ffff8d94ebbdb0c0     0 25801  23578 0x00000080
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:24 2024] Call Trace:
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:24 2024]  [<ffffffffa4e1c352>] ? kmem_cache_alloc+0x1c2/0x1f0
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:24 2024]  [<ffffffffc0577227>] ? kmem_zone_alloc+0x97/0x130 [xfs]
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:24 2024]  [<ffffffffa5368c49>] schedule+0x29/0x70
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:24 2024]  [<ffffffffa536a535>] rwsem_down_write_failed+0x225/0x3a0
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:24 2024]  [<ffffffffc05778e4>] ? xlog_grant_head_check+0x54/0x100 [xfs]
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:24 2024]  [<ffffffffc05667dd>] ? xfs_vn_update_time+0xcd/0x150 [xfs]
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:24 2024]  [<ffffffffa4f870a7>] call_rwsem_down_write_failed+0x17/0x30
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:25 2024]  [<ffffffffa5367f4d>] down_write+0x2d/0x3d
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:25 2024]  [<ffffffffc0569544>] xfs_ilock+0xc4/0x120 [xfs]
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:25 2024]  [<ffffffffc05667dd>] xfs_vn_update_time+0xcd/0x150 [xfs]
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:25 2024]  [<ffffffffa4e5e5c8>] update_time+0x28/0xd0
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:25 2024]  [<ffffffffa4e5e710>] file_update_time+0xa0/0xf0
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:25 2024]  [<ffffffffc055c3bd>] xfs_file_aio_write_checks+0x18d/0x200 [xfs]
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:25 2024]  [<ffffffffc055c6a8>] xfs_file_dio_aio_write+0xc8/0x340 [xfs]
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:25 2024]  [<ffffffffa4cd6530>] ? try_to_wake_up+0x190/0x390
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:25 2024]  [<ffffffffc055cce2>] xfs_file_aio_write+0x102/0x1b0 [xfs]
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:25 2024]  [<ffffffffc055cbe0>] ? xfs_file_buffered_aio_write+0x2c0/0x2c0 [xfs]
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:25 2024]  [<ffffffffa4e97b33>] do_io_submit+0x3e3/0x8a0
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:25 2024]  [<ffffffffa4e98000>] SyS_io_submit+0x10/0x20
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:25 2024]  [<ffffffffa5375ddb>] system_call_fastpath+0x22/0x27
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:25 2024] INFO: task mysqld:25802 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:25 2024] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:25 2024] mysqld          D ffff8d94f0b85140     0 25802  23578 0x00000080
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:25 2024] Call Trace:
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:25 2024]  [<ffffffffa5368c49>] schedule+0x29/0x70
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:25 2024]  [<ffffffffa536a27d>] rwsem_down_read_failed+0x10d/0x1a0
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:25 2024]  [<ffffffffc05695d0>] ? xfs_ilock_data_map_shared+0x30/0x40 [xfs]
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:25 2024]  [<ffffffffa4f87078>] call_rwsem_down_read_failed+0x18/0x30
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:25 2024]  [<ffffffffa5367f00>] down_read+0x20/0x40
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:25 2024]  [<ffffffffc056955c>] xfs_ilock+0xdc/0x120 [xfs]
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:25 2024]  [<ffffffffc05695d0>] xfs_ilock_data_map_shared+0x30/0x40 [xfs]
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:25 2024]  [<ffffffffc054f9ca>] __xfs_get_blocks+0x9a/0x6d0 [xfs]
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:25 2024]  [<ffffffffa4c79912>] ? get_user_pages_fast+0x122/0x1a0
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:25 2024]  [<ffffffffc0550e24>] xfs_get_blocks_direct+0x14/0x20 [xfs]
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:25 2024]  [<ffffffffa4e848f6>] do_blockdev_direct_IO+0xf96/0x20a0
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:25 2024]  [<ffffffffc0550e10>] ? xfs_setfilesize+0x80/0x80 [xfs]
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:25 2024]  [<ffffffffa4e85a55>] __blockdev_direct_IO+0x55/0x60
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:25 2024]  [<ffffffffc0550e10>] ? xfs_setfilesize+0x80/0x80 [xfs]
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:25 2024]  [<ffffffffc0550e30>] ? xfs_get_blocks_direct+0x20/0x20 [xfs]
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:25 2024]  [<ffffffffc055c759>] xfs_file_dio_aio_write+0x179/0x340 [xfs]
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:26 2024]  [<ffffffffc0550e10>] ? xfs_setfilesize+0x80/0x80 [xfs]
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:26 2024]  [<ffffffffc0550e30>] ? xfs_get_blocks_direct+0x20/0x20 [xfs]
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:26 2024]  [<ffffffffc055cce2>] xfs_file_aio_write+0x102/0x1b0 [xfs]
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:26 2024]  [<ffffffffc055cbe0>] ? xfs_file_buffered_aio_write+0x2c0/0x2c0 [xfs]
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:26 2024]  [<ffffffffa4e97b33>] do_io_submit+0x3e3/0x8a0
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:26 2024]  [<ffffffffa4e98000>] SyS_io_submit+0x10/0x20
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:26 2024]  [<ffffffffa5375ddb>] system_call_fastpath+0x22/0x27
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:26 2024] INFO: task mysqld:25803 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:26 2024] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:26 2024] mysqld          D ffff8d94f0b830c0     0 25803  23578 0x00000080
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:26 2024] Call Trace:
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:26 2024]  [<ffffffffa4e1c352>] ? kmem_cache_alloc+0x1c2/0x1f0
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:26 2024]  [<ffffffffc0577227>] ? kmem_zone_alloc+0x97/0x130 [xfs]
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:26 2024]  [<ffffffffa5368c49>] schedule+0x29/0x70
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:26 2024]  [<ffffffffa536a535>] rwsem_down_write_failed+0x225/0x3a0
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:26 2024]  [<ffffffffc05667dd>] ? xfs_vn_update_time+0xcd/0x150 [xfs]
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:26 2024]  [<ffffffffa4f870a7>] call_rwsem_down_write_failed+0x17/0x30
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:26 2024]  [<ffffffffa5367f4d>] down_write+0x2d/0x3d
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:26 2024]  [<ffffffffc0569544>] xfs_ilock+0xc4/0x120 [xfs]
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:26 2024]  [<ffffffffc05667dd>] xfs_vn_update_time+0xcd/0x150 [xfs]
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:26 2024]  [<ffffffffa4e5e5c8>] update_time+0x28/0xd0
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:26 2024]  [<ffffffffa4e5e710>] file_update_time+0xa0/0xf0
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:26 2024]  [<ffffffffc055c3bd>] xfs_file_aio_write_checks+0x18d/0x200 [xfs]
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:26 2024]  [<ffffffffc055c6a8>] xfs_file_dio_aio_write+0xc8/0x340 [xfs]
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:26 2024]  [<ffffffffa4cd6530>] ? try_to_wake_up+0x190/0x390
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:26 2024]  [<ffffffffc055cce2>] xfs_file_aio_write+0x102/0x1b0 [xfs]
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:26 2024]  [<ffffffffc055cbe0>] ? xfs_file_buffered_aio_write+0x2c0/0x2c0 [xfs]
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:26 2024]  [<ffffffffa4e97b33>] do_io_submit+0x3e3/0x8a0
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:26 2024]  [<ffffffffa4e98000>] SyS_io_submit+0x10/0x20
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:26 2024]  [<ffffffffa5375ddb>] system_call_fastpath+0x22/0x27
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:26 2024] INFO: task mysqld:25804 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:26 2024] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:26 2024] mysqld          D ffff8d94ea39e180     0 25804  23578 0x00000080
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:27 2024] Call Trace:
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:27 2024]  [<ffffffffa4e1c352>] ? kmem_cache_alloc+0x1c2/0x1f0
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:27 2024]  [<ffffffffc0577227>] ? kmem_zone_alloc+0x97/0x130 [xfs]
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:27 2024]  [<ffffffffa5368c49>] schedule+0x29/0x70
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:27 2024]  [<ffffffffa536a535>] rwsem_down_write_failed+0x225/0x3a0
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:27 2024]  [<ffffffffc05667dd>] ? xfs_vn_update_time+0xcd/0x150 [xfs]
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:27 2024]  [<ffffffffa4f870a7>] call_rwsem_down_write_failed+0x17/0x30
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:27 2024]  [<ffffffffa5367f4d>] down_write+0x2d/0x3d
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:27 2024]  [<ffffffffc0569544>] xfs_ilock+0xc4/0x120 [xfs]
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:27 2024]  [<ffffffffc05667dd>] xfs_vn_update_time+0xcd/0x150 [xfs]
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:27 2024]  [<ffffffffa4e5e5c8>] update_time+0x28/0xd0
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:27 2024]  [<ffffffffa4e5e710>] file_update_time+0xa0/0xf0
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:27 2024]  [<ffffffffc055c3bd>] xfs_file_aio_write_checks+0x18d/0x200 [xfs]
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:27 2024]  [<ffffffffc055c6a8>] xfs_file_dio_aio_write+0xc8/0x340 [xfs]
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:27 2024]  [<ffffffffa4cd6530>] ? try_to_wake_up+0x190/0x390
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:27 2024]  [<ffffffffc055cce2>] xfs_file_aio_write+0x102/0x1b0 [xfs]
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:27 2024]  [<ffffffffc055cbe0>] ? xfs_file_buffered_aio_write+0x2c0/0x2c0 [xfs]
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:27 2024]  [<ffffffffa4e97b33>] do_io_submit+0x3e3/0x8a0
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:27 2024]  [<ffffffffa4e98000>] SyS_io_submit+0x10/0x20
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:27 2024]  [<ffffffffa5375ddb>] system_call_fastpath+0x22/0x27
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:27 2024] INFO: task mysqld:25809 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:27 2024] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:27 2024] mysqld          D ffff8d94b53b0000     0 25809  23578 0x00000080
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:27 2024] Call Trace:
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:27 2024]  [<ffffffffa5368c49>] schedule+0x29/0x70
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:27 2024]  [<ffffffffa536a27d>] rwsem_down_read_failed+0x10d/0x1a0
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:27 2024]  [<ffffffffc055b1b4>] ? xfs_file_fsync+0xc4/0x1c0 [xfs]
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:27 2024]  [<ffffffffa4f87078>] call_rwsem_down_read_failed+0x18/0x30
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:27 2024]  [<ffffffffc055b0f0>] ? xfs_file_readdir+0x40/0x40 [xfs]
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:27 2024]  [<ffffffffa5367f00>] down_read+0x20/0x40
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:27 2024]  [<ffffffffc056955c>] xfs_ilock+0xdc/0x120 [xfs]
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:27 2024]  [<ffffffffc055b1b4>] xfs_file_fsync+0xc4/0x1c0 [xfs]
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:27 2024]  [<ffffffffa4e762e7>] do_fsync+0x67/0xb0
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:27 2024]  [<ffffffffa4e765d0>] SyS_fsync+0x10/0x20
[Mon Mar 25 14:40:28 2024]  [<ffffffffa5375ddb>] system_call_fastpath+0x22/0x27
```

Is there something wrong with the OS or XFS?

Comment: What is the current value of hung_task_timeout_secs?

Comment: You tagged this `mysql` -- what query were you running?

Comment: # cat /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs
120

Comment: There are a lot of queries executed in mysql, up to thousands, but the queries themselves are very fast, almost at the millisecond level. There are also about a dozen writes to the sql that are blocked.

Comment: Please provide sample queries and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: It is the disk that causes system performance.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide WRITE SPEED enhancing suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.